# WM_KEYDOWN processed by the ActiveX parent - how to disable it

Tags: activex, internet-explorer

I implemented an IE plugin (ActiveX) that has some inputbox controls on it. Each time when I press TAB or Backspace, the container (main IE window) will also process those events. Is there any way to stop propagating the WM_KEYDOWN to the parent window?

Thanks,
Cristian

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement [IInputObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761804(VS.85).aspx)?  If so, make sure your HasFocusIO() implementation is correct.

Comment: I did so, but those 3 functions are never called. The plug-in is a content extension ActiveX

Comment: Do you respond to IID_IInputObject in your QueryInterface() function?

Comment: Also, is your control windowed or windowless?

Comment: What do you mean by *respond to IID_IInputObject*, I don't explicitly call QueryInterface with that IID, I let the framework do the job. Somehow if I call DoVerbUIActivate(0,0); at the end of the OnCreate function, than TranslateAccelerator* will be called. The construction is a bit complex, the COM ActiveX starts the CLR and then a custom control (.net) is loaded.